# Two questions about the itemchanged and itemerror events

Tags: powerbuilder

Within PB6.5.1 and PB9.0：

Question 1:
 In itemchanged event:
    return 1
 In itemerror event:
    return 3
At runtime,the sequence of events fired is:
   itemchanged-->itemerror-->itemchanged-->itemerror
Why is each event fired twice？

Question 2：
  In itemchanged event:
     return 1
  In itemerror event:
     return 2
At runtime,the focus did not move to the next cell. 
Why？

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Question 1:** By returning 3 from `itemerror`, you have rejected the data, which clears the column and triggers the `itemchanged` again.

As to philosophically why PowerBuilder is designed to work in this fashion, I suspect they thought it would follow the principal of least surprise i.e. they were anticipating people asking why rejecting the input did not trigger `itemchanged`.

**Question 2:** The `itemchanged` event overrides `itemerror`.  In `itemchanged` you rejected the input *and* prevented focus changing; in `itemerror` you now accept the input, but you have not removed the block on focus changing.  You should return 2 from `itemchanged`, since you can then control whether you allow focus to change from the `itemerror` event, by returning either 1 or 3.

---

In case anyone is reading this question without the powerbuilder help files handy:

return values for `itemchanged`:

> 0  (Default) Accept the data value
>   1  Reject the data value and do not allow focus to change (triggers itemerror)
>   2  Reject the data value but allow the focus to change (triggers itemerror)

return values for `itemerror`:

> 0  (Default) Reject the data value and show an error message box
>   1  Reject the data value with no message box
>   2  Accept the data value
>   3  Reject the data value but allow focus to change

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It looks not be mentioned in the PowerBuilder help that itemerror event returning 3 will trigger itemchanged event,doesn't it？

Comment: Relevant pages from the online docs (see ItemChanged and ItemError): http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dc37783_1150/html/dwref/BABCJGCA.htm